# How do I de-duplicate iPhone messages in the text message history?

Tags: iphone, ios, backup, messages

Some bad data backup/recovery software caused most texts in my message history (inside of "Messages" app in iOS) to get duplicated (repeated) 8X.

**BEFORE**
Alice: Hello, Bob. 
Bob: Hello, Alice.

**AFTER**
Alice: Hello, Bob.
Alice: Hello, Bob.
Alice: Hello, Bob. 
Alice: Hello, Bob. 
Alice: Hello, Bob. 
Alice: Hello, Bob. 
Alice: Hello, Bob. 
Alice: Hello, Bob.
Bob: Hello, Alice.
Bob: Hello, Alice.
Bob: Hello, Alice.
Bob: Hello, Alice.
Bob: Hello, Alice.
Bob: Hello, Alice.
Bob: Hello, Alice.
Bob: Hello, Alice.

I'm guessing that solving this problem would be a 3-step process:

1. Backup the Messages data from iPhone to PC.
2. Modify the contents of the backup (delete duplicate messages).
3. Restore the Messages data from PC to iPhone.

Can anybody recommend a tool set, API, or open-source code for accomplishing this on a Windows PC? Note: If I had to, I could also get access to a Mac.

Comment: This site is *Apple Specific.* If you want to do it on Windows you will need to take it over to https://superuser.com. I would edit the question to be Mac-specific or move it over to SuperUser.

Comment: At the end of the post, I mentioned that I'd be able to do it on a Mac, despite my Windows preference.